# Office 2019 - Can't deactivate COM addins

Tags: ms-office, office-addins

After installing Office 2019 x64 as a volume license, I realize that I can't permanently deactivate COM add-ins.

For example, From the add-ins COM menu of Outlook, when I deactivate the "Outlook social connector 2016" or "OneNote Notes" add-ins, the add-ins stay deactivate until I shut down the application.

When I restart outlook, the add-ins reload at startup.
I didn't have this behavior with Office 2021 x64.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

My XML configuration install :

```
<Configuration ID="5226d950-b00c-4ee2-9ff5-7bef739b764b">
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019" SourcePath="\\10.1.1.44\Scripts$\Office_ODT\Office_2019" AllowCdnFallback="TRUE">
    <Product ID="Standard2019Volume" PIDKEY="6NWWJ-YQWMR-QKGCB-6TMB3-9D9HK">
      <Language ID="fr-fr" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="PinIconsToTaskbar" Value="TRUE" /> 
  <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE" />
  <Property Name="DeviceBasedLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SCLCacheOverride" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />
  <Updates Enabled="FALSE" />
  <RemoveMSI All="True" />
  <AppSettings>
    <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\excel\options" Name="defaultformat" Value="51" Type="REG_DWORD" App="excel16" Id="L_SaveExcelfilesas" />
    <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\powerpoint\options" Name="defaultformat" Value="27" Type="REG_DWORD" App="ppt16" Id="L_SavePowerPointfilesas" />
    <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\word\options" Name="defaultformat" Value="" Type="REG_SZ" App="word16" Id="L_SaveWordfilesas" />
  </AppSettings>
  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su].